# Sorting an ArrayList / HashMap with key

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList

```
    static ArrayList<term> terms = new ArrayList<term>();
```

and a HashMap

```
    static HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> inverted_index = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

This is my class term

```
    public class term {
int docID;
String tokenName;

public term(String tokenName, int docID)
{
    this.tokenName = tokenName;
    this.docID = docID;
}

public int getDocID() {
    return docID;
}
public String getTokenName() {
    return tokenName;
}

public String toString(){
    return tokenName + " " + docID ;
}}
```

I want to sort it by tokenName.
I did this

```
    Collections.sort(terms, new Comparator<term>(){
        public int compare(term term1, term term2){
            return term1.tokenName.compareTo(term2.tokenName);
        }
    });
```

Now when I print terms, I do get the sorted order.
Now I call this function

```
    public static void createInvertedIndex(){
    inverted_index.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<terms.size(); i++){

        ArrayList<Integer> doc_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(!inverted_index.containsKey(terms.get(i).tokenName)){

            doc_list.add(terms.get(i).docID);
            if(i+1 < terms.size()){
                if(terms.get(i).tokenName.equals(terms.get(i+1).tokenName)){
                    while((i+1 < terms.size()) && terms.get(i).tokenName.equals(terms.get(i+1).tokenName))
                    {
                        i++;
                        doc_list.add(terms.get(i).docID);
                    }
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(terms.get(i)); ------ Get Sorted Terms here
            inverted_index.put(terms.get(i).tokenName, doc_list);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(inverted_index); // ------ Get Unsorted terms in this
}
```

I don't get sorted inverted_index.
Do I need to sort it too?
If so, how to do that?

I want the output in sorted order.

Comment: You might want to rename your variables to respect Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inverted_index` is a `HashMap` and `HashMap` is not sorted. You need to use a [`SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) for this, like [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: Suppose I want to output the HashMap in sorted order, what should I do?

Comment: `HashMap` has no order; `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order you put things in, and `TreeMap` sorts according to the `Comparable` order of the keys.

Comment: code please..I cannot understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I suggest that you read the Javadoc for [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: I suggest reading about data structures, in particular what a hashmap actually is.